# SharePoint 2013 - App Deployment

Tags: sharepoint-addin, deployment

i need some best practices or advices on a common scenario in SP2013 where i can't get my head around as i'm fairly new to App development.

Let's say i have some kind of existing site structure and created an app that i want to place on a certain place on some Pages. I don't want the user to that and from my understanding i can't use the APP Catalog for this because this just puts the app in the available apps but not on a certain page.

In 2010 my approach would be to create a feature, installed that and activated it through ps for all existing sites. During the activation of the feature (for example a site collection feature) all of the placement would have taken place. For new pages i maybe feature stapeling would be the choice.

For SharePoint 2013 i was wondering if webtemplates could be the way to archive this but i think when the app is removed and reinstalled it is missing on all pages where it used to be before etc. (App install only fires once etc.)

I hope my problem is understandable. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I hope you know that its not necessary to make ONLY apps in SP 2013, you can do 2010 kind of development (making features etc.) on SP 2013 as well..

Comment: I'm wondering if there is a Kind of Administration Approach to place apps on sites instead of having the user do that. Like i tried to explain: If i add an app through the app catalog to sites it is still up to the user to place the app somewhere. But what i'm asking for is, how is an admin able to place an app on directly to designated sites.
Another example may be: Think of an Enterprise application that is mandatory to be placed on certain sites to fullfill some Kind of Business process. I can't let the users Choose if they install the app on the page or not... I'm not really asking if this

Comment: Do you want to place webparts on site page via powershell? This link might help you: http://adicodes.com/adding-web-part-to-page-with-powershell/

Answer (score 1):

What do you want your 'app' to do?

Sounds like, for your scenario, Apps aren't the best choice.

Think of Apps as single units of functionality that work in their own subsite away from the rest of your site (as that's pretty much what they are).

Answer (score 0):

You don't really place the app itself on pages, you add the app part(s) to pages. App parts function similar to web parts that are connected to the app which has its own app web. More specifics on what you are looking to do would help to provide you with more on what you're looking for.

Comment: The App part is actually an IFrame showing a specific page from the app web